# cards permutations

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

This Question is from HackerRank : Alice was given the $n$ integers from $1$ to $n$ . She wrote all possible permutations in increasing lexicographical order, and wrote each permutation in a new line. For example, for $n=3$, there are $6$ possible permutations:

1.[1,2,3]

2.[1,3,2]

3.[2,1,3]

4.[2,3,1]

5.[3,1,2]

6.[3,2,1]

She then chose one permutation among them as her favorite permutation.

After some time, she forgot some elements of her favorite permutation. Nevertheless, she still tried to write down its elements. She wrote a  $0$ in every position where she forgot the true value.

She wants to know the sum of the line numbers of the permutations which could possibly be her favorite permutation, i.e., permutations which can be obtained by replacing the $0$s. Can you help her out?

For Example $[0, 2, 3, 0]$ could be $ [1,2,3,4]$ or $[4,2,3,1]$ and the sum of indexes of these permutations are $ 1+22 = 23 $.

For me to code it, if i try all valid permutation given that let say there are $20$ numbers missing or Alice forget them then we are talking about sum for $20! \approx 2.4*10^{18}$, so there must be a simpler way or a formula ?

Comment: Presumably the permutations are indexed in standard order? That is, for $4$ slots, we have $(1234,1243,1324,1342,\cdots,4312,4321)$. Is that right?

Comment: What is mean by "line numbers of the permutations"?

Comment: @Eric, OP wrote "lexicographical order", which is probably what you mean by "standard order".

Comment: "line numbers" are the little numbers on the left in the given example, I assume.

Comment: For a start, you might see if you can come up with a way to convert a permutation to its lexicographic index, i.e. "line number".

Comment: @awkward there is a way which is $(p_i-1) (n-1)!$ and then relabel the remaining, the problem is with relabelling when too many missing numbers.

Comment: With regard to the missing numbers.... Hint: Do you know how to generate all the permutations of a set of numbers?

Comment: @awkward no!!!!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oops, my bad, I should have caught that. OP, I have no direct hints at the moment but I'm certain there are patterns we can use, i.e. we should be able to make a list of all the size-$n$ permutations where $k$ is in position $a$, and then intersect from there. So in your example, find the set of indices of all permutations where $2$ is in the second position $\{1,2,15,16,21,22\}$ and the equivalent set for $3$ in the third position $\{1,6,7,12,19,22\}$, then find the intersection.

Comment: @EricSnyder isn't that that still exponential time in the number of missing numbers? Which I think is what Ahmad is trying to avoid...

Comment: @MichaelHartley exactly that, not that i don't know how to convert a permutation to it's index, the problem with $n$ missing numbers is that there are $n!$ permutations you have to deal with, and since this question deals with large number there must be a quick way.

Comment: @MichaelHartley You have a good point which OP notes. I just can't think of a quick way at all. While lexicographical order isn't arbitrary, it sort of is with respect to this problem. I don't see how a simple process leads to the sum.